# Need Advices for Building Charts in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, charts

I would like to know, what would be a good way to display statistics about and application execution after it finishes off. The statistics, in my situation, would be the occurrence of each `number, lowercase character and uppercase character` typed during the whole process. It is a WPF C# Application.

I thought about charts, since they make it easier to visualize data, maybe one chart to each `category` (numbers, lowercases and uppercases) but, i dont wan't it to be cluttered and uggly.

It would be OK for example to display a `Pie Chart` with numbers occurence, because 0 to 9 would lead to only 10 entrances, at most, because a number may not be typed at all.

The problem is that, when it comes to `characters` i might have up to 26 entrances for a chart. Which kind of chart can i use to avoid a cluttered and messed display of data ?

The chart must show each `input` (such as '0', '1', '2' in the case of numbers chart, and 'A','B','C' for the Uppercase chart) with its own `Count`.

Comment: I think you are going to need to build the various options and test with real data to decide what displays best.  If some characters dominate you may need to go with a log scale to compress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might help you choose a proper charting metod. [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/196502/WPF-Toolkit-Charting-Controls-Line-Bar-Area-Pie-Co) is a nice example.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, i will give this framework a try. But, my question is, which kind of chart should i use ? Pie, Columns, Lines... Got it ?
I want to avoid a messed display of data, since there will be a lot of information.

Comment: Also, my app is a WPF aplication. runat="server" is not avaible there :D

Comment: No need to apologize, you came to help, no problem :D